# rich text editor for writing article into website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tested ckeditor and tinymce, well both of them is okay but it just not giving end user much costumization and also it not works well with my bootstrap based site, like making table and image, image is not responsive unless i edit from the source which is not very user friendly for end user and table, oh i hate when someone put table into article, it look okay in desktop but nightmare in mobile devices... and also i just can't add class into image, table or

tags without editing in source view...

so I wondering what is profesional choice? website like theverge, engadget and other have a great layout in their article. so are they using somekind super awesome rich text editor or they write every article in html code?

Comment: Dreamweaver? for both content editing and testing on devices !!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: "can't add class" ... yes you can. You haven't really provided a legitimate problem in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Summernote](http://summernote.org/) its quite good. And about making image responsive, when you get raw format from text editor to store in your database simply replace `<img` with `<img class='img-responsive'`.

Do the same with other tags because there are not much free text-editors with tables and all, that generates html code with bootstrap classes.